# Calculate $\int x\sqrt{x^2 - 4x} \mathrm{d}x$...

Tags: integration

I've attempted it by parts, by substituting $x - 2 = 2\sec{u}$ and even by substituting $x - 2 = 2\cosh{u}$, and I always get stuck after simplifying the various expressions. May I have a hint?

Furthermore, I'm not exactly sure the solution given in Wolfram Alpha is correct, or the simplest possible.

Thanks very much.

Comment: How about just $t=x-2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use $x-2=2\sec \theta$ as you suggested.

$$\int x\sqrt{x^2 - 4x} \mathrm{d}x=\int x\sqrt{(x-2)^2-4}dx = \int (2\sec\theta+2)2(\tan\theta) \sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta\\=4\int (\sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta+\sec\theta\tan^2\theta)=4\int \sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta +4\int \sec\theta\tan^2\theta $$

**Edit**

Yes, you need second substitution separately as follows.

As for first term, use $u=\tan\theta$, then
$$4\int \sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta= 4\int u^2 du=\frac{4}{3}u^3=\frac{4}{3}\left[\left( \frac{x-2}{2} \right)^2-1\right]^\frac{3}{2}=\frac{1}{6}\left[ x^2-4x\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

As for second term, observe that

\begin{align*}
\int \sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta&=\int \sec^3\theta d\theta -\int\sec\theta d\theta
\\&= \tan\theta\sec\theta-\int\sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta-\int \sec\theta d\theta
\end{align*}

Thus,
\begin{align*}
4\int \sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta&=4\left(\frac{\tan\theta\sec\theta-\int \sec\theta d\theta}{2}\right)=4\left(\frac{\tan\theta\sec\theta-\ln{(\tan\theta+\sec\theta)}}{2}\right)\\
&= 4\left(\frac{x-2}{4}  \left[ \left(\frac{x-2}{2} \right)^2-1  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)  -4\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(   \left[ \left(\frac{x-2}{2} \right)^2-1  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} +\frac{x-2}{2}  \right)\right)\\
&= \frac{x-2}{2}  \left[ x^2-4x  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}  -2\ln\left(  \frac{ \left[ x^2-4x  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} +(x-2) }{2} \right)
\end{align*}

Thus, your answer would be
\begin{align*}
\int x\sqrt{x^2-4x}dx &= \frac{1}{6}\left[ x^2-4x\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{x-2}{2}  \left[ x^2-4x  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}  -2\ln\left(  \frac{ \left[ x^2-4x  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} +(x-2) }{2} \right) \\
&=\frac{(x-3)(x+2)}{6}\left[ x^2-4x  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} -2\ln\left(  \frac{ \left[ x^2-4x  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} +(x-2) }{2} \right) 
\end{align*}

Comment: I presume the integral you've provided requires a second substitution to carry on?

Comment: @SRSR333 You are right!  I just added detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int x\sqrt{x^2-4x}\,dx=\int\left((x-2+2)\sqrt{x^2-4x}\right)\,dx=\int(x-2)\sqrt{x^2-4x}\,dx+\int2\sqrt{x^2-4x}\,dx$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Euler substitution ..........

Take  $$\sqrt{x²-4x} = tx $$and proceed

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)